# how to move azure GIT repos file from one folder to another folder using Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-repos, azure-git-deployment

Here is my scenario:

I have a scenario where after a successful git push to a deployment folder (SSIS and TSQL scripts) in azure repos, I have to move the files in deployment folder to multiple archival folders inside the repos(SSIS and TSQL) after successful build. I need to achieve this with azure devops build and release process. any help is really appreciated.

Comment: This is an X-Y problem. You don't need to move scripts around in source control after deployment, you need to ensure that the scripts are idempotent so that it's safe to run them multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `CopyFiles` task and git command to copy and push files in the repo. Check the sample below:

```
steps:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: 'deployment'
    Contents: '**'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/archival1'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: 'deployment'
    Contents: '**'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/archival2'

- script: |
   git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
   git config --global user.name "Your Name"
   git checkout master
   git add $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/archival1/** $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/archival2/**
   git status
   git commit -m "copy files"
   git push origin master
```

If you want to delete the `deployment` folder after copying the files, you could add the following to the pipeline:

```
- task: DeleteFiles@1
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: 'deployment'
    Contents: '**'
    RemoveSourceFolder: true

- script: |
   git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
   git config --global user.name "Your Name"
   git checkout master
   git add $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/deployment/**
   git status
   git commit -m "delete deployment folder"
   git push origin master
```

**Notice:**

You need to [grant version control permissions to the build service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#grant-version-control-permissions-to-the-build-service):

[image]

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is your issue solved?