# Use Existing Page for Azure DevOps Wiki Folder

Tags: azure-devops, wiki

I have been reworking the wiki we have. It is a repo/git based wiki, not just straight on devops. In it there are folders, and each folder has a markdown file of the same name. When clicking on the folder, I want that file to be opened. Instead, I get a message about adding page contents, but that will fail as we PR into the wiki.

Is there some way for me to get the DevOps wiki to recognize the existing pages with the same name? Is there something that needs to be in the file?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sub-pages (e.g. the file named *Getting Started.md*) need to be in the root.

When you have a folder and sub-page (both with the same base name) within the root directory, then in the wiki it'll show as a combined unit (when the user clicks on *Getting Started* folder they'll see the text from *Getting Started.md*).

You can as part of your workflow move those pages like *Getting Started.md* to the root (see this reference: [how to move azure GIT repos file from one folder to another folder using Azure Devops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66323959/how-to-move-azure-git-repos-file-from-one-folder-to-another-folder-using-azure-d))

Comment: Thanks! That solved it. I was looking way to long for some magic file to resolve this!